# React Native - Header Title on Material Bottom Tabs on Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a Material Bottom Tabs into a Stack Navigator in Navigation 5.

It is suppose dto get the title and route it throught a function but doesn't work.

function:

```
function getHeaderTitle(route) {
  const routeName = route.state
    ? route.state.routes[route.state.index].name
    : route.params?.screen || 'Home';

  switch (routeName) {
    case 'Favorites':
      return 'Favorites';
    case 'Info':
      return 'Info';
  }
}
```

materialBottomTabs

```
const NavTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Favorites"
        component={FavoritesScreen}
        options={({route}) => ({
          tabBarLabel: 'Fav',
          tabBarIcon: () => IconFav(),
        })}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Info"
        component={InfoScreen}
        options={({route}) => ({
          headerTitle: 'Info',
          tabBarLabel: 'Info',
          tabBarIcon: () => IconInfo(),
        })}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

stackNavigator

```
<NavigationContainer>
 <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={NavTab}
      options={({route}) => ({
        headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route),    
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Detail"
      component={ItemDetailScreen}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>;
```

I easly set the title of a screen listed in the Stack.
Example:

```
const ItemDetailScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: item.title,
    });
  }, []);
```

But I can't set the title of the screens into the material bottom tabs. They always have the name set into the stack navigator. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  options={({route}) => ({
    headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route),    
  })}
```

i think it should be:

```
  options={({route}) => ({
    title: getHeaderTitle(route),    
  })}
```